# Stuck on creating first web application

Tags: html, css, web

I'm hitting a roadblock while attempting to develop my first web application. I am new to web design/development and I have just recently created my first website: http://amritayalur.com/.

I am trying to create a large search box, along with a submit button that will take the user's input and get results back through the use of an API. (I know how to do this). What I need help on is creating this large search box and saving the users input to a file, variable or something.

I did something like this on an android application, but I'm struggling with HTML and CSS. It would be really cool if I could get a search box similar to the ones found here: https://www.tumblr.com/.

Comment: How new are you? Like, how much do you know about CSS and Javascript?

Comment: Which API are you using? Do you mean that the search box will search your site? Likely, you will be submitting a POST to your webserver, the server will take the results, do something with it, and generate pages for the user to see. However, I have also seen client-side (Javascript) searching, so it really depends.

The site look great! Keep working on your programming and don't hesitate to ask for help at places like this. I wish I had started when I was 16 instead of 20.

Comment: :-) first of all: do not use comic-sans-ms ... :P

Comment: What language are you using for the backend? This will determine suggestions for how to save information on backend.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guys! I'm not looking to search my own website, I want to take the user's input and use it to retreive data using the Tastekid API. [link](http://www.tastekid.com/page/api). As far as a backend, I haven't really thought about it yet. I don't think a database of any sort is necessary, but I'm still in the early stages of development.

Comment: @Slicekick How long do you need this data to stay available?  As long as the browser is open, persisting across browser tabs and sessions, or "permanently"?

Answer (score 3):

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: #3C5A76;;   
}

.large-input {
    color: #869CB2;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 12px 0 0 11px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    width: 176px;
}
</style>

<body>
    <input type="text" class="large-input">
</body>
```

This code as jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cJCP7/

Comment: Why would you even bother to include Helvetica if you put Arial before it?? Do the right thing and always put Helvetica *before* its cheap knock-off, Arial.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I just copy/pasted the CSS from the site OP wants to base his design on. That's how they do it at Tumblr, OP wanted something similar, why should I argue?

Answer (score 0):

here's another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danferth/7vSgN/) with a submit button.  the part on grabbing the input value and passing it to a variable part will need to be done with `PHP` or `javascript` depending on what you wanted to do with it.  Also if you are looking for a search box as in search your site try the [google search](http://www.google.com/cse/)

Answer (score -2):

Never save information in a file. Always save it into a DB like MySql, postgresql, etc.

Comment: This is a very broad, general and unspecific statement. There are many cases where the complexity of a relational dbms is pure overkill when file-based or other persistence mechanisms are the better fit. This is 2011, well 2012 almost, and NoSQL solutions have become pretty mature nowadays.